# Query in SQL in a Database

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I need your help to write a query in SQL for a database. Imagine this case:

Database where there are 3 columns (ID, Material, Quantity)

| id | material | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 30 |
| 2 | X | 15 |
| 3 | Y | 20 |

I would like to get last quantity entry for Material X from Database. My idea is to do the following:

```
SELECT quantity 
FROM table 
WHERE name = 'X' 
AND ID = ( SELECT max( ID ) FROM table)
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to get value 15. It only works if I search last row only (in this case for material Y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the table for `name = 'X'`, sort the results by `ID` in descending order and get the top row with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT quantity 
FROM tablename 
WHERE name = 'X' 
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Material ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn
   FROM table
)
SELECT material,quantity
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

In this way you can see the result for "X", "Y" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query is not correlated to your main query and is returning max id over whole table. Change to

```
SELECT quantity 
FROM table t 
WHERE name = 'X' AND 
ID = (SELECT max(ID) FROM table t1 where t1.name = t.name)
```